# Sustainable Query Per Seconds [QPS] without incurring in timeout errors

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout, google-cloud-datastore, contention

Do you know which is the *safest* [Queries Per Second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queries_per_second) rate in update on a single entity without incurring in write contention?
Reading [this](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) document about sharding it clearly says:

> it is important to note that you can
>   only expect to update any single
>   entity or entity group about **five
>   times a second**. That is an estimate
>   and the actual update rate for an
>   entity is dependent on several
>   attributes of the entity, including
>   how many properties it has, how large
>   it is, and how many indexes need
>   updating.

I'm having [timeout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745538/google-app-engine-timeout-the-datastore-operation-timed-out-or-the-data-was-tem) even with one update per second and a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745538/google-app-engine-timeout-the-datastore-operation-timed-out-or-the-data-was-tem/4745806#4745806) answer has baffled me:

> You can still get write contention on
>   individual entities if you're doing
>   more than about **1QPS** of modifications
>   to them

Am I missing something?
How could my GAE app scale if I can't even update a single entity per second without incurring in Timeout errors?

Comment: I don't know if 5 updates per second or 1 update per second is the safe number.  But in either case, that rate is for 1 entity, not your entire app.  So you app can still scale just fine - you could have a hundred different entities being updated per second, serving a hundred different users.  App Engine is focused on serving web apps, which generally need to scale horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: @Peter fair enough, I still don't get how could is possible to get a timeout updating an entity 1 time per second though.

Comment: if you don't get an answer here you could try asking at the next IRC chat.

Comment: Did the 1 QPS figure come from an article referencing the new high replication datastore ?  writes supposedly take longer on that system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the variance is because this isn't a hard limit. If you do 1 QPS of updates to an entity group, you probably won't notice any significant increase in timeouts or latency at all. If you do 5 QPS, you'll probably see an increased rate of timeouts, and noticeably higher latency. Beyond that, contention issues will get worse.

Generally, I think of 1 QPS as the design goal to build around, to give a reasonable margin of error for spikes.

Comment: thanks, I think you (Google) should update that sharding article to a more correct 1 QPS. As said in the other question, I have tuned the rate of the task queue that updates the single entity to 1 task per second; I'm still getting some few Timeout errors. Could the high number of reads on the entity increase the possibility of Timeouts even if the entity is updated just 1 time per second?

Comment: Reads won't increase timeouts; some low number of timeouts are expected at any level of writes, though. About what percentage of writes do you see timeouts on?

Comment: *some low number of timeouts are expected at any level of writes* that explains everything. I'm having from 1 to 5 timeouts everyday but with a number of writes > 2000 so it's a tiny tiny percentage. I simply thought that lowering the rate to 1 task per second in updates would allowed me to keep the logs clean; thanks for your clarification.